# Link in <select> dropdown options with handlebars partials

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I'm trying to create a dynamic dropdown list with an option to redirect to another page if you click "view".

I was able to do this with HTML which redirected to a new html page based on the option clicked:

```
 <td><select name="viewpo" id="viewpo" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
                <option>Edit</option>
                <option value="viewpo.html">View</option>
                <option value="holdpo.html">On Hold</option>
              </select>
              </select></td>
```

However, since I decided to use Handlebars partials, I realized I can't hardcode the above HTML code since the links are dependent on the page that is shown. I.E. If it's an employees page, it'll redirect to an employees view page. If it's a PO page, it'll redirect to an employees view page.

I decided to do my handlebars partial like this:

```
 <table class="table table-striped employee ">
  <thead>
    <div class="row">
      <tr class="headerrow">
    </div>
{{#each tableColumns as |column|}}
      <th>{{column.value}}</th>
    {{/each}}
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each tableData as |row|}}
      <tr>
        {{#../tableColumns as |col|}}
          <td>
            {{#if col.editable}}
              <select id="myList" name="myList" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
                <option>Edit</option>
                {{#if active.employees}}
                <option value="../viewemployees">View</option>
                {{/if}}

                {{#if active.PO}}
                <option value="../viewPO">View</option>
                {{/if}}
                    <option>Delete</option>
                  </select>
            {{else}}
              {{lookup row col.name}}
            {{/if}}
          </td>
        {{/../tableColumns}}
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My goal is to have the view link in the partial to change the link based on which page is active. The HTML code given above works (but need it dynamic instead of hardcoding per screen), but when I include the #if in the partial, whenever I click view, it doesn't do anything.

Index.js

```
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({defaultLayout: 'main'}));

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

app.use('/static', express.static('public'));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('employees', { active: {employees: true}, data: employeeData, columns: employeeColumns, pageHeader: "Employees"});
});

app.get('/po', (req, res) => {
  res.render('po', { active: {PO: true}, data: poData, columns: poColumns, pageHeader: "Purchase Orders"});
});
```

Comment: does your viewemployees and viewPO pages exist ? At top you explain that your page is viewapo.html and now it is viewemployees. I don't understand why you change the structure of your select.

Comment: My mistake. Edited the HTML. Yes i have a viewemployees and viewPO page. The problem is the option to View in between the {{#if}} isn't showing up, but if I remove it, it shows up

Comment: Try to test what value you have in active variable by printing it with {{active}} it is probably empty

Comment: it's printing out object Object

Comment: Then try {{active.employees}} or try to console.log active

Comment: it comes out as true, so i dont understand why it isn't performing the action of <option value="../po">View</option>

Comment: Try to see if adding {{else}} will enter the else or if nothing is showing up. If else is entered thé maybe that you have a problem with the data (maybe a Space or something like that)